# How does Python represent bytes literal

Tags: python-3.x, byte

For example, why is the following expression true?

```py
b'5QUU' == b'\x35\x51\x55\x55'
```

And how can I see alternative representations of the same `bytes`?

Comment: Maybe it helps to view the integers: `print(ord(b'Q'), 0x51)`

Comment: So in the above example, the LHS is like an "ACSII" representation, and the RHS is like a "Hex" representation of the same byte string. But how can I let python show me a specific representation - say I'm more interested in knowing the hexadecimals.

Comment: You can use [hex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex) method.